# API for PL/SQL to Neo4j equivalent

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-java-api

Is any API or tool available to convert PL/SQL procedure, functions to neo4j equivalent ?? Currently I use Oracle 10 as my data source and planning to switch to Neo4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not such a tool. Also it could be hard to do that, because Oracle is a RDBMS and Neo4j is a Graph database.

I'm not saying it's not possible, but you'll doing it once and it's better to write them by your own. And then ask here on StackOverflow if you aren't sure how to replicate in the Neo4j.

Comment: Thank you for your response.